# ASP: Copying a file path in full into my code-behind method

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, file-upload, webforms

I want to copy an excel file to my database. The problem I'm having is I cant seem to copy the path from  into the code-behind. This is my asp code:

```
    <asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="UploadButton" text="Upload" onclick="UploadButton_Click" />
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />
```

if I hard code in a path then my code will work:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\moynik\Desktop\datatest.xls";
```

but if I use the following line I only get a different path that will not work.

```
string path = Path.GetFullPath(FileUploadControl.FileName);
```

but I need to make my path dynamic so users can upload from different destinations on there own computer. Can anyone help me out. this is the function which works and copys the excel file to my database

If this is impossible can someone help me with a solution if they think of one. Thanks

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\moynik\Desktop\datatest.xls";
            string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";



    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
            {
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand ("Select Name,Address,Age FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);

                connection.Open();

                using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                { 
                    string sqlConnectionString = "SERVER=<servername>;UID=schafc;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=<dbname>;";

                    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
                    {
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "<tableName>";
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                    }
                }
            } 
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to provide a web page with something like path structure to let user to choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName)` instead of `.GetFullPath`.

http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/

EDIT: Ah, I've just worked out what you're trying to do. You need to upload the xls file to a *server* location first, and then you can pass the path to the file on the server into the connection string.

e.g.

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
string path = Server.MapPath("~/") + filename;
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(path);

string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The FileUpload control is a server side control, and the code

```
Path.GetFullPath(FileUploadControl.FileName);
```

is executed on the server, and not on the client side. I'm not sure what you mean by "I need to make my path dynamic so users can upload from different destinations on there own computer". The users can always select files from any destination on their computer.

Answer (score 1):

The file does not actually exist on your server disk until you save it somewhere. See the MSDN documentation for [FileUpload.SaveAs Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx). The only reason your manually specified path is working is because the app is on your dev machine and therefore has access to the file. In effect, what you're doing with the hardcoded path is byapssing the upload control entirely.

```
string path = Path.Combine(@"C:\MyUploadDirectory", FileUploadControl.FileName);
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(path);
string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
```